# Creating a "category" of featured posts

Tags: posts, categories

I would like to have a category page named "Featured Articles" that simply lists all sticky posts. I know an alternative is creating an actual category called "Featured Articles" and adding every sticky post to it, but that seems a bit redundant.

I thought it would be possible by building a `WP_Query`, but how can I get it to show within the structured permalink and category base settings? And how would I build the query?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the latter part of the question, you can use this article for reference: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-the-latest-sticky-posts-in-wordpress/ and also the WP documentation here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts

The sticky posts can be obtained with:

`$sticky = get_option('sticky_posts');`

Then the query:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $sticky,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

That will give you what you need